# Recommendations for testing a windows application in a productive system

Tags: windows, stress-testing

we have to test our (not self developed) system.
It's a delphi app (windows client), java server (running on AIX) with an SQL Server.
My question is what is the best strategy for a (automated) stress test.

Thank you for your support!

Stefan